# Oscoomerce tep_create_random_value($length, 'digits'); function not working

Tags: php, updates, oscommerce

This function `generate_cart_id()` not working. Oscommerce after updating PHP version 5.6 to 7.2.

File: **catalog/includes/classes/shopping_cart.php**

```
function generate_cart_id($length = 5) {
  return tep_create_random_value($length, 'digits');
}
```

Comment: Could you please share what error you catch?

Comment: this methods can't generate random number and return blank.

Comment: Make sure that `bcmath` PHP's extension has been installed. ([how to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478844/how-do-i-see-the-extensions-loaded-by-php))

Answer (score 0):

try this function, we use it for our [oscoommerce templates](https://solomono.net/oscommerce-templates/c-382.html) on php 5.4 - 7.4:

```
function tep_create_random_value($length, $type='mixed') {
if (($type!='mixed') && ($type!='chars') && ($type!='digits'))
    return false;

$rand_value='';
while (strlen($rand_value) < $length) {
    if ($type=='digits') {
        $char=tep_rand(0, 9);
    }else {
        $char=chr(tep_rand(0, 255));
    }
    if ($type=='mixed') {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]$/i', $char))
            $rand_value.=$char;
    }elseif ($type=='chars') {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i', $char))
            $rand_value.=$char;
    }elseif ($type=='digits') {
        if (preg_match('/^[0-9]$/', $char))
            $rand_value.=$char;
    }
}

return $rand_value;
```

}