# can not find *"extension=php_fileinfo.dll"* in my php.ini file?

Tags: php, laravel, fileinfo

i tried to insert an image into mysql database but i got that error "Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?)."

i only found this extension *extension=fileinfo* i uncommented it but still getting the same error

i tried to open the php.ini file and i didn't find the *"extension=php_fileinfo.dll"* then i added it but still got the same error .

anyone faced the same issue please ?

Comment: did you restart your server between changes?

Comment: yes i did but nothing happend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see the extensions loaded by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478844/how-do-i-see-the-extensions-loaded-by-php)

Comment: i found that fileinfo is already installed i don't now why it's not working !

Comment: Did you verify in your fpm installation too ? like do `dd(get_loaded_extensions());` in a controller and check for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know where your configuration file is located using

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

on the sixth-ish line, you have `Loaded Configuration File` with the file path next to it.

uncomment/add the extension line in that file (dll for windows)

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and restart your server.