# PHP wont see ImageMagic enabled

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, laragon

I have a Laragon enviroment and a project that uses PHP 7.4.
My 7.4 has ImageMagic enabled in the `.ini`, the `.dll` file is in the .ext directory.

I even installed the latest ImageMagic for Windows.

And yet, I get this error:

`You need to install the imagick extension to use this back end`

The project is using `Simple QrCode` package by SimpleSoftareIO.

Not sure what else could I be required to do in order to enable ImageMagick and also not sure what other information I can provide to make solving this easier.

Comment: Do a phpinfo() and make sure you edited the right .ini

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can not find \*"extension=php\_fileinfo.dll"\* in my php.ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72461713/can-not-find-extension-php-fileinfo-dll-in-my-php-ini-file)

Answer (score 0):

Install imageMagick from the official website https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

and then move all the files into your PHP installation folder.