# Error from Composer: "you must enable openssl extension"

Tags: php, composer-php

I use XAMPP server and I use php version 8.0.0

I tried to create a Laravel project and this error appeared:

> In ComposerRepository.php line 1155:
>
> You must enable the openssl extension in your php.ini to load information from https://repo.packagist.org

Comment: So please enable openssl in your environment. (and restart the service)

Comment: i enabled it from apache configuration but nothing happened

Comment: Did you edit the correct (CLI) php.ini? Did you check that it is in fact enabled? `php -m`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478844/how-do-i-see-the-extensions-loaded-by-php

Comment: how can i know it it correct php.ini or not because i edit the php.ini from the apache server configuration

Comment: `php -i` will show you `phpinfo()` information on your terminal. There's a "_Configuration File (php.ini) Path_" and a "_Loaded Configuration File_" somewhere at the top

Comment: Yes i ensure that i edit the correct file

Answer (score -1):

For solving this error, you must open php.ini and remove the semicolon to:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

If you don't have that line inside php.ini, check you have the file ( C:\xampp\php\ext) and add this to php.ini in the "Dynamic Extensions" section:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: in the C:\xampp\php\ext file and don't have php.ini

Comment: you php.ini is located inside C:\xampp\php; You should check php_openssl.dll is available inside C:\xampp\php\ext or not

If that not available then install it manually